# Rust - Enum variant that references a struct

Tags: struct, rust, enums, lifetime

I am new to rust. I have this code:

```rust
enum Foo {
    F1 { x: Vec<Foo>, y: i32 },
    F2 { x: &Bar },
}

struct Bar {
    x: i32,
    y: Vec<Foo>,
}
```

Obviously, this won't compile, because I have to give a lifetime param, which leads to this:

```rust
enum Foo<'a> {
    F1 { x: Vec<Foo<'a>>, y: i32 },
    F2 { x: &'a Bar<'a> },
}

struct Bar<'a> {
    x: i32,
    y: Vec<Foo<'a>>,
}
```

Is using lifetimes like this good practice? In this case, I need `F2` to have a reference to `Bar`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by best practice. It depends on the scenario whether references are needed or not, right? If you have references in your struct, lifetimes are threre anyway. It's just that sometimes you don't need to speicfy them due to lifetime elision. If you wanted to, you could specify lifetime parameters on every reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime annotations you have written are appropriate for this situation. (There are other cases where it might be preferable to use multiple lifetime parameters, such as when dealing with `&mut` references, to avoid over-constraining lifetimes, but this is not such a case.)

However, it *might* be that you actually don't want to use a `&Bar` at all, but some other type such as `Box<Bar>` or `Rc<Bar>` that owns the `Bar` struct. In that case, you *won't* need the lifetime annotations. Whether this is that case depends on how these structures are constructed and used, so it can't be determined from just the type declarations — but you'll find out via compile errors when you try to use them, if so.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Would that be good practice in the long term (as I add more enum variants like that in `Foo` and use the enum more)?

Comment: @xilpex For "would this be good practice" to be answerable, there needs to be _some alternative to consider_, and there isn't enough context on the situation, as you've written your question very generically, to describe anything that's different enough to be interesting (such as using a different data structure).